# How to Limit while (iterator.hasNext()) iterations?

Tags: java, netbeans, while-loop, infinite-loop

I am working on Java using the Generex library, to **print strings against given regular expressions**.

Some of the R.Es can generate **infinite strings**, I just want to handle them, but couldn't yet.
My code looks like;

```
Generex generex = new Generex(regex);
Iterator iterator = generex.iterator();
    System.out.println("Possible strings against the given Regular Expression;\n");
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.print(iterator.next() + " ");
    }
```

If I input (a)* as a regular expression, the output should look like this

```
a aa aaa aaaa aaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa ...
```

How do I limit the result of that loop?

Comment: And what are the criteria?

Comment: Have you tried maintaining a counter? For instance, `int maxIterations = 10; while(iterator.hasNext()) && maxIterations-- > 0) { … }`. You could come up with a similar solution if you don’t want to create strings of a length greater than N.

Comment: I got it know. Helpful. :)

Comment: Criteria for the regular expression is to use only {a,b,(,),*}. Against each R.E, the possible or if infinite some of the strings be printed or so..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, I think the length of the string is much more important than the number of elements printed so I would say the following solution is probably better :

```
Generex generex = new Generex(regex);
Iterator iterator = generex.iterator();
System.out.println("Possible strings against the given Regular Expression;\n");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int limitOfChars = 100; //for example
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String next = iterator.next();
    if (sb.length() + next.length() > limitOfChars) break;
    sb.append(next + " ");
}
System.out.println(sb.toString() + " ... ");
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's say you wish to print the first 8 items, and then add `"..."` if there are more items to print. You can do it as follows:

```
int limit = 8;
int current = 0;
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    if (current != 0) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.print(iterator.next());
    // If we reach the limit on the number of items that we print,
    // break out of the loop:
    if (++current == limit) {
        break;
    }
}
// When we exit the loop on break, iterator has more items to offer.
// In this case we should print an additional "..." at the end
if (iterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.print(" ...");
}
```

Comment: put limit compare into while condition using '&&' instead of using'break'

Comment: @boly38 That's another option, yes. I decided to put a `break` because the limiting logic is, in a way, separate from the "main" iteration-stopping logic, but that's a matter of personal preference.